# Git doesn't see any changes I've made to my files between local and remote

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I was using SourceTree and ran into an issue with the repository not being found despite the fact that it is there.

I tried this trick to fix that:

```
git remote rm origin

git remote add origin 
https://GITHUB_USERNAME:PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN@github.com/GITHUB_USERNAME/REPO_NAME.git
```

As soon as I ran this, the `1` next to master listing all my changes on my latest commit vanished. Now no matter how many times I push, the latest commit is never sent to github.

When I run `git status` I get:

```
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Running `git log` shows my latest commit is in fact there locally.

I have many files that were changed, so I know there isn't anything wrong with gitignore. It also showed the changes were ready to push until I did the two commands above.

`git update-index --really-refresh` does not fix it.

This also didn't work:

```
rm .git/index

git reset
```

Switching it back to `git@github.com:myuser/myrepo.git` just results in the same not found error as before.

How do I fix this?

Comment: run `git fetch` to download the state of your new remote, and `git branch -u origin/master master` if you want to have git compare your local `master` branch with its remote counterpart

Comment: `git remote add origin https://GITHUB_USERNAME:PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN...` - this will leave your access token in the config file in plain text - you should set set up a credential helper instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is happened to me a few month ago. This is how I solved this issue:

1. I clone my project from GitHub to a new folder
2. I copy all of my files from the old folder to the new project that I cloned in step 1
3. Add a new existing folder to SourceTree
4. Commit new change and push to GitHub

Viola; now I can remove my old folder.

Answer (score 0):

As far as setting up your repo after changing remotes goes:

- run `git fetch` to download the state of your "new" remote,
- run `git branch -u origin/master master` if you want to have git compare your local master branch with its remote counterpart

---

As far as debugging your ssh access issues: use the command line ssh client to debug your ssh access

```
ssh git@github.com:myuser/myrepo.git
ssh -v git@github.com:myuser/myrepo.git
```

check if this command sends the ssh key you expect from your own system to authenticate on github